# jQuery empty select but not the first option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm loading two dropdowns using jQuery AJAX in WordPress. I'm getting AJAX data as a string, and I'm simply appending those `<option>`s to my `<select>` field. It's working fine. But every time it's not clearing the previous append. So it's actually adding repeating options.

So I made a change, I added `empty()` to the `<select>` field:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {"action": "load_product",
            "company_id": company_id
          },
    success: function (data) {
        jQuery('#company-products').empty().append( data );
    }
});
```

But I have an empty value option in the select field by default, it's simply removing that one too.

```
<select name="product" id="company-products" class="form-control" required>
    <option value=""><?php _e( 'Select a product', 'textdomain' ); ?></option>
</select>
```

How can I append the additional options, but not empty even with the empty (`value=""`) one.
Please note, I know I can pass the empty field from jQuery, but for translation purpose I can't pass that from there. So I want a solid solution using jQuery, while the first option stays.

I even tried changing it to:

```
jQuery('#company-products').not(':first-child').empty();
jQuery('#company-products').append( data );
```

It's not working, even not appending anything. :(

Comment: Use [gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `nextAll()` - to remove all elements after the empty `<option>`

```
var emptyOp = $('#company-products :first-child');

emptyOp.nextAll().remove();
emptyOp.after(data);
```

**[Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46ax9ne2/)**

There are many other selectors you can use,

```
$('#company-products :gt(0)').remove();
$('#company-products').append(data);
```

OR

```
$('#company-products :not(:first-child)').remove();
$('#company-products').append(data);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `empty()` just use `remove()`.

```
$('#company-products').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

hope this will works for you

Answer (score 0):

What if you just try to write

```
<?php _e( 'Select a product', 'textdomain' ); ?>
```

JS variable and pass you option as you write, from jQuery?

```
var selectOption = '<?php _e( 'Select a product', 'textdomain' ); ?>';
```

Comment: Good try! But it's showing everything, but somehow not showing the text: http://prntscr.com/6ptvtb

Comment: Yo need to write this in your php code before your JS script.

Comment: Actually you should never pass unescaped texts to JS in this way. In this case you should have to use [`esc_js()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_js/). But the WordPress recommended way of passing translation strings, dynamic data is [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).